# Using KVO with custom keys

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm curious here, but it is possible to implement KVO using custom keys (and manual change notification)?

So for example, can I register like this:

```
[myObject addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"My custom string" options:0 context:nil];
```

And send out a change notification like this:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"My custom string"];
// do something
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"My custom string"];
```

I tried this out in a small test app and it works, but I'm curious whether anyone has used this or seen value in it.

Comment: You could also use NSNotificationCenter for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that if the key doesn't correspond to a property, you shouldn't be using KVO. However, it should be noted that a property doesn't need instance variables or even accessors. You can implement a dynamic property entirely with Key-Value-Coding-compliant methods. Such a property would only be accessible using KVC, though (e.g. `-valueForKey[Path]:` and `-setValue:forKey[Path]:`).

For example, if you implement `-valueForUndefinedKey:`, you can examine the key and, if it matches the name of a dynamic or virtual property (using whatever criteria you desire), you can return the appropriate value. Likewise, if you implement `-setValue:forUndefinedKey:`, you can make that property writable.

For that case, you don't necessarily have to emit manual KVO change notifications. KVC will emit those automatically when you call `-setValue:forKey[Path]:`. However, if you change some internal state which effectively changes the value of the property, you do have to emit the change notifications yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is simply to be notified of some event, it's better to just post a custom event to `NSNotificationCenter` and register for that.

If you're going to implement KVO for some custom property, then you really want to make sure your custom property is [KVO Compliant](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE), which includes that it should be KVC compliant. As the docs say:

> In order to be considered KVO-compliant for a specific property, a class must ensure the following:
>
> - The class must be key-value coding compliant for the property, as specified in “[Ensuring KVC Compliance](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172)”.
>
>   KVO supports the same data types as KVC.
> - The class emits KVO change notifications for the property.
> - Dependent keys are registered appropriately (see “[Registering Dependent Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-BAJEAIEE)”).
>
> There are two techniques for ensuring the change notifications are emitted. Automatic support is provided by `NSObject` and is by default available for all properties of a class that are key-value coding compliant. Typically, if you follow standard Cocoa coding and naming conventions, you can use automatic change notifications—you don’t have to write any additional code.
>
> Manual change notification provides additional control over when notifications are emitted, and requires additional coding. You can control automatic notifications for properties of your subclass by implementing the class method `automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:`.

In short, there's a lot more involved to KVO than `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey`.

---

I would suggest that you either implement KVO fully (and full KVO/KVC compliance is pretty easy if you're just synthesizing standard properties; it is a little more complicated if you want to do it manually), or don't use KVO at all, and use other interfaces, such as the notification center:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveNotification:) name:kMyNotificationKey object:nil];
```

With a handler like:

```
- (void)didReceiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // do whatever you want here
}
```

And notifications are posted with:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kMyNotificationKey object:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could, but you are mis-using the mechanism.

The notifications that supply the before and after value information won't work correctly if the keys you use don't match the properties you are changing. I think CrimsonChris has the right idea. Use notifications if what you are doing is simply  triggering an event. That's what the notification manager is for.